# Distinct elements from Array by property in PHP

Tags: php, data-structures

I have set of students as php objects. each students has id, name, department as properties.

I want to get distinct list of departments from the students array.

Is there any build in function or easy methodology without iterating through array of students?

Comment: show structer of the array. array_colunm() works with array of objects only since php 7. To get distinct use array_unique()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are dealing with array list than please check [array-column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: Looks great. how to handle distinct?

Comment: do use `array_unique` function for distinct list :)